# Clock and counter in the same window

Tags: python, tkinter

I can't remove a label from this code at the end of countdown
the idea is to have a clock and a countdown timer for an event and at the end of the counter I want it to disappear.

```py
from tkinter import *
import time

win = Tk()
win.geometry('400x400')
frame=Frame(win)
frame.grid()
labelTD=Label(frame)
labelTD.grid(row=2,column=0)

def clock():
    t=time.strftime('%A''\n''%D''\n''%I:%M:%S',time.localtime())
    if t!='':
        labelTD.config(text=t,font='infra 50 bold',foreground='black',background='white')
        labelTD.update_idletasks()
        labelTD.after(1000,clock)

def countdown():
    for t in range(12,-1,-1):
    
        Mn = t % 60
        Hr = t // 60

        if int(Hr)<10 and int(Mn)<10:

            xmn = str(Mn).zfill(2)
            xhr = str(Hr).zfill(2)
            label1 = Label(frame, text=(xhr+':'+xmn))
            label1.grid(row=1)

        else:

            label1 = Label(frame, text=(str(Hr).zfill(2)+':'+str(Mn)))
            label1.grid(row=1)

        frame.update()
        time.sleep(1)


labelTD.grid(row=2,column=0)
clock()
countdown()

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `after()` for the countdown as well and create the label for countdown outside the function:

```py
labelCD = Label(frame)
labelCD.grid()

def countdown(n):
    hr, mn = divmod(n, 60)
    labelCD.config(text=f"{hr:02}:{mn:02}")
    if n > 0:
        labelCD.after(1000, countdown, n-1)
    else:
        labelCD.destroy()

countdown(12)
```

---

Update: Show `hh:mm:ss` in `countdown()`:

```py
def countdown(n):
    mn, secs = divmod(n, 60)
    hr, mn = divmod(mn, 60)
    labelCD.config(text=f"{hr:02}:{mn:02}:{secs:02}")
    if n > 0:
        labelCD.after(1000, countdown, n-1)
    else:
        labelCD.destroy()
```

Comment: @ acw1668 Thank you! its working
but may I know what is wrong with my code? why destroy or forget don't work?

Comment: I noticed this: in countdown I want to show hour:minute:second, if i put 2hr and 30 minute I can't get that format, what i'm getting is minute and second and showing 120:00

Comment: You haven't call `destroy()` in `countdown()` in your posted code.  Use `mn, secs = divmod(secs, 60)` and then `hr, mn = divmod(mn, 60)`.

Comment: @ acw1668 I used mn, secs=divmod(n,60) then hr, mn =divmode(mn,60)
Thank you again

Comment: @ acw1668, I have a personal project is there a way i can contact you to get some advice and guidance, I'm new with coding and want to learn.